# Collect synchronize data from different sensor in Android

Tags: java, android, database, timestamp, sensors

I  doing an app that collect data from the different sensor that are in a smart-phone. My doubts are : how I can collect different data? My goal is create an Matrix of array. There are the data capture from the signal in every row in the same time.
If I use "timestamp " in the code above, it could be ok? I am not sure, because the definition of timestamp is "the time on which the event occur", but the problem is that the event can occur only in one sensor. Sincerely I am a bit confused about it.

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    }`enter code here`

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            //TODO: get values
        }else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
            //TODO: get values
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could benefit from a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). In your case i see it as a `TreeMap<Long, Map<Integer, Float>>`

The TreeMap will map timestamps (which you can get with `System.currentTimeMillis()` to whatever measurements were taken at those moments. The fact that it's a TreeMap will sort the entries according to the keys (so they will be in ascending order relative to the timestamps)

The measurements are a `Map<Integer, Float>` which maps sensor types that took measurements to the values of the measurements (which i will assume to be Float).